# How to parse JSON data to model class and display in multiple recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Hello I am creating a multiple horizontal recycler view layout which holds multiple recycler view.

JSON dummy data below

```html
{
  "MyData":
   [{"headerTitle":"Fruits","listItem":[{"image":"https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/png/20180903/orange-png-png_75700.jpg","name":"Orange","hname":"Fruits"},{"image":"https://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/apple/9-apple-png-image-thumb.png","name":"Apple","hname":"Fruits"},{"image":"https://5.imimg.com/data5/RM/TY/MY-13308502/fresh-watermelon-500x500.png","name":"Watermellon","hname":"Fruits"},{"image":"https://c7.uihere.com/files/947/615/656/banana-food-fruit-clip-art-bananas-png-clipart-image-thumb.jpg","name":"Banana","hname":"Fruits"},{"image":"https://png.pngtree.com/element_pic/00/16/09/0657ce7dc878850.jpg","name":"Cherry","hname":"Fruits"}]},{"headerTitle":"Pizza","listItem":[{"image":"https://www.pngarts.com/files/3/Pizza-PNG-Image.png","name":"Pizza 1","hname":"Pizza"},{"image":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcSpqnkJ4gzZaWEbOYeMaqz3yV-VxRrCBplog_3t8OaBkCDf3RCRWw","name":"Pizza 2","hname":"Pizza"},{"image":"https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/11/02/4dc2c71756d114bf0f3333a33514ffa4.jpg","name":"Pizza 3","hname":"Pizza"},{"image":"https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/rebanada-de-pizza-png-1.png","name":"Pizza 4","hname":"Pizza"},{"image":"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcTWVHTyPRtMWuw3Wx0sn-bsOrLCYqy2di2QUfw4V75uchLbrfYT","name":"Pizza 5","hname":"Pizza"}]},{"headerTitle":"Drink","listItem":[{"image":"http://pngimg.com/uploads/cocktail/cocktail_PNG155.png","name":"Drink 1","hname":"Drink"},{"image":"https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/135691/isolated/preview/175702226dd92b9a70d23b87ebed4a5d-cocktail-drink-by-vexels.png","name":"Drink 2","hname":"Drink"},{"image":"https://s7d9.scene7.com/is/image/SAQ/cosmo-golden-gate-ec?$saq-fiche-cocktail$","name":"Drink 3","hname":"Drink"},{"image":"https://www.belvederevodka.com/upload/maraschino-vermouth-belvedere-vodka-martini.png","name":"Drink 4","hname":"Drink"},{"image":"https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/09/27/1057e9dc08462c6.jpg","name":"Drink 5","hname":"Drink"}]},{"headerTitle":"Wine","listItem":[{"image":"http://www.probottleshots.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/napa-bottle-photographer-Tinacci.jpg","name":"Wine 1","hname":"Wine"},{"image":"http://www.pngpix.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/PNGPIX-COM-Wine-Bottle-PNG-Transparent-Image-1-500x1025.png","name":"Wine 2","hname":"Wine"},{"image":"https://pronto-core-cdn.prontomarketing.com/2/wp-content/uploads/sites/1633/2016/03/l-creek-shiraz-cab-no-vintage-transparent-background.jpg","name":"Wine 3","hname":"Wine"},{"image":"https://png.pngtree.com/element_pic/17/07/21/3f0516b906aa8dd783c6e0aefaa52567.jpg","name":"Wine 4","hname":"Wine"},{"image":"http://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/stock-images/old-glass-bottle-corkscrew-mdnO39D-600.jpg","name":"Wine 5","hname":"Wine"}]}]
 
}
```

everything working perfectly but model class not adding data row-wise means repeating same data in all child recyclerview from JSON data.

what i want-: i want to load data separately for each recyclerview from JSON by using "listItem".

Here my codes

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("MyData");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject dataobj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String headerTitle = dataobj.getString("headerTitle");
                JSONArray listViewData = dataobj.getJSONArray("listItem");

                SectionDataModelSearch dm = new SectionDataModelSearch();
                dm.setHeaderTitle(headerTitle);

                // looping through All that
                for (int j = 0; j < listViewData.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject c = listViewData.getJSONObject(j);
                     image = c.getString("image");
                     name = c.getString("name");
                    singleItem.add(new SingleHandleSearchModel(name,image));
                }
                dm.setAllItemsInSection(singleItem);
                allSampleData.add(dm);
            }
        }
catch( final JSONException e){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FAILED" + "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

i know i am getting wrong data from JSON data. please help me.

Comment: anyone can help me i am waiting for your reply

Comment: _i know i am getting wrong data from JSON data._ What do you mean? Please be more specific, and clarify what exactly you're struggling with. See [ask], [help/on-topic].